# What can I do about carrots having weak stems?

Tags: vegetables, seedlings, germination, carrots, support

Should I plant then deeper, fill in dirt around them as they are growing or perhaps something else?

It seems like they grow faster than they can keep up with themselves, and if I do nothing, I'd end up with a ton of right angled carrot stems.

Is this why seedling starters are used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't pile soil around carrots, higher than the crown. Weak stems is an indicator of too fast of growth/too little light. If the stems seem stretched/pale, increase the light. If they are big and healthy, but soft and weak, it might be a fertilizing issue. Both of these things will keep the plants from forming good roots.

Also, some carrots I've grown did tend to put out leaves at a right angle, while others tended to stay upright.